# Where can I find possible rules for vscode key bindings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've googled for this (perhaps poorly?) and I can only seem to find list of key bindings for vscode. So far I haven't found any list of the rules you can add to key bindings (in the `when`-part). Right now for example, I want to find out if there's a way to make sure a key binding is only active if I have the version control sidebar up and focused. Kind of like:

`filesExplorerFocus`, `terminalFocus`, `editorTextFocus` and `explorerViewletFocus`.

Since there is a command for setting the focus to the version control sidebar: `workbench.view.scm` I've experimentally tried `scmFocus` but to no luck.

Now this is a specific problem, but I'd really like to save myself some time and just be able to run a few ctrl+f through a document of all possible when-rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vscode when clause commands](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_when-clause-contexts).  I only found it through this issue - so there may be a few other undisclosed when clauses: [when clause disclosure issues.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/641)  I see nothing for when the version control sidebar is active though.  Perhaps ask about it at that issues page above.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584576/836330 and especially https://stackoverflow.com/a/65584576/836330