# How do I find out the names of Views in VS Code which are accessible from the Activity Bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When you click on item on **Activity bar**, that item window is opened in **Side bar**. For example: `SearchViewletVisible` and `ExplorerViewletVisible` for **Explorer** and **Search** resp. There are other items on my activity bar, like **extensions**, **debugger**, **outline** e.t.c, How can I get their names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`activeViewlet: "workbench.view.debug"`

and the same for the others, like

`activeViewlet: "workbench.view.extensions"`

You can check these for yourself by using the `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` command and then searching for `debug` for instance to see if you get anything promising.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62202897/836330 for how to use the `Context Keys` command.

And https://stackoverflow.com/a/62523863/836330 on how to use these values in a keybinding.

Answer (score 0):

@mark's answer above worked nice, but people who are new to vs code (like me) would not understand where to search for the item name, so for those people:

To find out the name of `activeViewlet` or `focusViwlet` or any other thing,  Toggle `developers options` from `ctrl+shift+p`, and search for your item in the last item of the `console` in `developers options`.

Comment: can you please clarify? did not understand

Answer (score 0):

If it's a builtin view, you can probably find the name listed in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#visiblefocused-view-when-clause-context or https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#visible-view-container-when-clause-context.

For extension-contributed views, you can also look at the extension manifest file for the extension (find the extension under `~/.vscode/extensions` and then find its package.json file), and look for [the `contributes` > `viewsContainers` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.viewsContainers) and [the `contributes` > `views` property](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.views).